# Count symbols in a list

Tags: function, scheme, racket

How can i create a function countSymbols that takes a nested list of numbers and symbols as input, and returns the count of all symbols in the input list.

```
(countSymbols '(a)) returns 1
(countSymbols '(2 56 x (1 y))) returns 2
(countSymbols '(((a)) -2 (2 (ab b) (-1 0 1))))) returns 3
```

---

this is what i have tried

```
(define (countSymbols mylist)
  (if (null? mylist) 0
  (let ((c (car mylist)))
    (cond
      ((list? c) (+ (countSymbols c) (countSymbols (cdr mylist))))
      ((symbol? c) (+ 1 (countSymbols (cdr mylist))))
      (else (countSymbols (cdr mylist)))))))
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? post the code you've written, pointing the specific parts that are giving you trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be solved using the standard template for traversing a list of lists, which you should have already studied in class. I won't spoil the fun of writing your own solution, but instead I'll give you some hints - fill in the blanks:

```
(define (countSymbols lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) <???>) ; how many symbols in an empty list?
        ((not (pair? lst))  ; if this is a single elment of the list
         (if (symbol? lst)  ; check if it's a symbol, if so
             <???>          ; then we add one to the count
             <???>))        ; otherwise we add nothing
        (else               ; else we advance the recursion and add the
         (+ (countSymbols <???>)     ; result of both the `car` part
            (countSymbols <???>))))) ; and the `cdr` part of the list
```

It works as expected:

```
(countSymbols '(a))
=> 1
(countSymbols '(2 56 x (1 y)))
=> 2
(countSymbols '(((a)) -2 (2 (ab b) (-1 0 1))))
=> 3
```

Comment: this is what i have tried
(define (countSymbols mylist)
  (if (null? mylist) 0
      (let ((c (car mylist)))
        (cond
          ((list? c) (+ (countSymbols c) (countSymbols (cdr mylist))))
          ((symbol? c) (+ 1 (countSymbols (cdr mylist))))
          (else (countSymbols (cdr mylist)))))))